# Files in SMB share read-only after reconnect

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, samba

I use a remote file storage with SMBv3 access (Strato HiDrive). On Windows 10, I have this SMB share included as a network drive. When I open a file (e.g. in Excel), I can edit and save it just fine.
However, when the SMB share is reconnected (e.g. after waking up from standby) Excel insists that the file is read-only and changes cannot be saved. I can only save it to a different file name and then manually replace the old file.

Any idea what I can do to avoid this annoyance?

Previously, I had the storage included via WebDAV, where I didn't have this issue. I could revert back to that but was expecting SMB to be more stable and faster.